# Mobile media query not working

Tags: css, responsive-design

Alright, I'm at a complete loss. I've scoured the internet for a solution and it seems the only one thats working for people is this meta tag:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Problem is, I already have that in my header on all pages. The media queries work just fine on my index.php page, but when I style my other pages everything works except mobile. That is, tablet and desktop styles just fine. I have the standard

```
/*----Mobile Styling----*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

/*----Tablet Styling----*/

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

/*----Desktop Styling----*/

}
```

I'm at a complete loss, all of my brackets are closed, and my CSS looks alright. Anything else it could be?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what browser you are using on your smartphone. If you use `only`, it will block all older browsers from smartphones. So in this case try using:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

/*----Tablet Styling----*/

}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {

/*----Desktop Styling----*/

}
```

Comment: Just tried this, still nothing. It's so strange, I know my stylesheet is linked properly, my other screen sizes will style just fine. I am also running off of localhost right now, so I don't know if that changes anything.

Comment: @DrewBlaine try using `@media (max-width: 768px) { body { display: none !important } }` just to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Write  your media Queries like this. and put your media queries at the end of your main css.
eg. if your fonts size for desktop is 14px and for mobile its 10px. than in your css when you writes 14px should come first and than in media queries for mobile write 10px. Mismatch in ordering could be the problem in your code.

```
@media(min-width:320px) and (max-width:479px) {
//Mobile Portrait
}

@media(min-width:480px) and (max-width:767px) {
//Mobile Landscape
}

@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
//Tablet Portrait
}

@media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
//Tablet Landscape
}

@media(min-width:1200px) and (max-width:1600px) {
//Desktop and bigger devices
}
```